# Jquery Dynamic id manupulation

Tags: jquery

I am getting problem while dealing with the ids that are dynamically generated. I cannot understand how to manupulate these ids in jquery way.
I have following code for calculating totals

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/recopy/reCopy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{ 
var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">
Remove</a>';
$('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink}); });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{ 
$("input[id*='quantity']").keyup(function() 
{
        var totalSum = 0;
        $("input[id*='quantity']").each(function (){
        totalSum += parseFloat(this.value);
        });
    $("#grandtotal").val(totalSum);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">
<div class="clone" style="width:800px;">
    Quantity(Q):<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity">
    Rate(R):<input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate">
    Total Price(Q*R):<input type="text" name="total[]" id="total">
</div>
<div  style="width:700px;">
    <p style=" text-align:right;">
    Grand Total Price:
    <input type="text" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal" style="float:right">
    </p>
</div>
</br>                
<a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">Add More</a>    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me in this regard i am not getting total in each Price Id and then total of Price..

Comment: What you really want ?

Comment: Div of class clone increases / decreases dynamically. This increases the number of elements i.e quantity, rate and total. I want the total of every single div.

Comment: this is the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/wajahatdaar2/j6Dtf/ i want every total seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input[id*='quantity']", function () {
    var totalSum = 0;
    $("input[id*='quantity']").each(function () {
        totalSum += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    $("#grandtotal").val(totalSum);
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

### EDIT

As per comment, You need to first calculate total i.e. **(Q*R)**. Then You have to calculate **Grand Total**. I have done operation on keyup of rate change this according to your requirement.

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input[id*='rate']", function () {
    $(this).siblings('input[name="total\\[\\]"]').val(+$(this).val() * +$(this).siblings('input[name="quantity\\[\\]"]').val());

    var totalSum = 0;
    $('input[name="total\\[\\]"]').each(function () {
        totalSum += parseFloat(+$(this).val());
    });
    $("#grandtotal").val(totalSum);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Dtf/1/)

NOTE: As I have used name attribute. Thus escaped `[]`. As per docs

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

***Re-factored Code***

```
var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>';
$('a.add').relCopy({
    append: removeLink
});

$(document).on('keyup', "input[id*='rate']", function () {
    $(this).siblings('input[name="total\\[\\]"]').val(+$(this).val() * +$(this).siblings('input[name="quantity\\[\\]"]').val());
    calculateGrandTotal();
});

$(document).on('click', ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest('.clone').slideUp(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });

    return false;
});

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var totalSum = 0;
    $('input[name="total\\[\\]"]').each(function () {
        totalSum += parseFloat(+$(this).val());
    });
    $("#grandtotal").val(totalSum);
};
```

[**Re-factored DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Dtf/2/)

Comment: Div of class clone increases / decreases dynamically. This increases the number of elements i.e quantity, rate and total. I want the total of every single div.This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wajahatdaar2/j6Dtf i want every total seperately.

Comment: @wajahatdaar2, I have updated answer see working demo

Comment: @wajahatdaar2, See Re-factored DEMO in updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use event delegation.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input[id*='quantity']", function()  { ... }
```

Comment: Div of class clone increases / decreases dynamically. This increases the number of elements i.e quantity, rate and total. I want the total of every single div.This is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/wajahatdaar2/j6Dtf i want every total seperately.